# Oracle Distinct column to check

Tags: oracle

Currently my below script return to me the value of empty column as `Failed` and 
column with value as `Success` . My current issue is now I'm trying to add a distinct checking in the case when the column `transaction_id` has duplicate entry.
I'm trying to get the unique transaction. I'm out of idea if I'm still using the case function.

```
SELECT Count( case when trim(rpt_type) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
Failed, Count(case when trim(rpt_type) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
Success from daily_rpt where trunc(datetime) = '1-sep-2017';
```

Really need an enlightenment for me to proceed.

Sample DataType:-

```
DATETIME             |   TRANSACTION_ID    |   RPT_TYPE    |
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111111               
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111111               
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111113            WEB
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111112            ANDROID
```

Expected Result :

```
FAILED | SUCCESS 
   1       2
```

Scenario : I'm trying to get the count if the `rpt_type` is empty and the `transaction_id` has to be distinct

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It would help us help you

Comment: @Mureinik, i've just attached. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also share the result you'd like to get for this sample? I'm still trying to understand the requirement

Comment: @Mureinik, i've added some explanation in scenario and added some data for easier insight.

Comment: What if two rows have the same transaction id, and one has and rpt_type and the other doesn't? Is this counted as one success and one failure?

Comment: This seems a Bad design. If 2 rows have same DATETIME, TRANSACTION_ID, and RPT_TYPE, why they are there in the table? Please remove the duplicate rows use primary keys or indexes. BTW you just need a Distinct in case stmt

Comment: @Mureinik, it's counted as 1 success and 1 failure.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, i strongly agree with you. I don't have the access to restructure it.

Comment: **1)** Can it be that for one `TRANSACTION_ID` I get both a record with empty `RPT_TYPE ` and another with filled `RPT_TYPE`? Would you count this then as one failure and one success or as one success only? **2)** Can it be that for one `TRANSACTION_ID` I get two records with two different `RPT_TYPE`? If so, would you count this as one success only or two?

Comment: On a sidenote: You should not compare dates with strings. Especially not when they contain month or day names, as with different session settings these could easily fail. Use ANSI string literals instead: `trunc(datetime) = date '2017-09-01'`.

Comment: As I see from the accepted answer, both my questions above can be answered with "No, that is not possible", because otherwise you'd need a different query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
SELECT Count( DISTINCT case when trim(rpt_type) IS NULL  THEN TRANSACTION_ID ELSE NULL END) Failed
        , Count(case when trim(rpt_type) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Success
FROM DAILY_RPT
WHERE trunc(datetime) = '1-sep-2017';
```

Output:

```
Failed  Success
1   2
```

Hint
May be you used ='1-sep-2017' just for tests, but remember to used explicit conversion of string to date (TO_DATE()).

Changing your sample data adding two rows:

```
DATETIME             |   TRANSACTION_ID    |   RPT_TYPE    |
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111111               
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111111               
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111113            WEB
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111112            ANDROID
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111114               
01/09/2017 00:00:08          111115
```

My query returns

```
Failed  Success
3   2
```

Comment: Thank you @etsa , this really helps me in order to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT case when trim(rpt_type) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Failed
      ,Count(DISTINCT case when trim(rpt_type) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Success 
from daily_rpt where trunc(datetime) = '1-sep-2017';
```

Comment: How can this possibly work? Counting distinct values of 1 will return either 1 or 0.

Comment: @GoranStefanović, I didn't Notice this. Thanks for correcting me.